# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with LWJGL

Tags: java, lwjgl, noclassdeffounderror

So, I am afraid that I have to join the crowds flocking here and asking: "What's wrong with my code?"

I've recently started coding in Java and I've had none of this error until I tried using lwjgl in a project. So, the question is: What is wrong with my JAR when I get the following:

```
java -cp \lib\win32\lwjgl.jar -jar Valor.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/opengl/Display
    at bin.Disp.createWindow(Disp.java:18)
    at bin.Thread.gameLoop(Thread.java:13)
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.opengl.Display
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

As is, I am extremely confused about this. I've gone through seven or eight posts here about this very problem, and another five or six on other web sites, yet none of the methods those people used seem to work for me.

Currently, my file structure is:

```
Valor
  -Valor.jar
  lib
    win32
      -lwjgl.jar
      -lwjgl.dll
```

Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Main
```

I did try defining a classpath here... Didn't work. So, I'm pretty much as confused as I can possibly get. Thank you for your help.

Edit: This error doesn't occur while running in Eclipse, only when I export and try to run it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run it like this:

```
java -cp lib\win32\lwjgl.jar;Valor.jar Main
```

The problem is that the `-cp` option is ignored when `-jar` is used.

Alternativelly you could extend the class path by adding a `Class-Path:` entry in your manifest and puting `lib\win32\lwjgl.jar` in it.

```
Class-Path: lib\win32\lwjgl.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

use this link to install ljgl and define your classPath : http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse

Comment: I presume I have to extract the relevant native files, such as lwjgl-windows.jar, and then go into it to the windows directory and work from there, e.x. C:\tools\lwjgl323\lwjgl-natives-windows\windows\x64\org\lwjgl if I've extracted all my LWJGL archives to C:\tools\

Answer (score 0):

By running `java -cp \lib\win32\lwjgl.jar -jar Valor.jar` you're telling Java to look for LWJGL classpath near the root of your filesystem. Seeing your directory structure, use:

```
java -cp .\lib\win32\lwjgl.jar -jar Valor.jar
```

Notice the `.` at the beginning.